# Magento 2 Error 500 after admin login (apache)

Tags: magento2, admin, apache

I recently installed the current magento 2 version (fresh install) on an apache server. Everything worked as intended until I logged into the admin panel, which results in an internal server error. As my access to log-files is very limited due to hosting (domain factory) I hope that someone could just throw a few possible solutions at me which I could try out to solve the issue. .htaccess file is the original one (magento 2 installed via composer).

Roundup:

- Apache Webserver with php7.0.6
- Fresh Magento 2 install via composer
- original .htaccess
- Frontend works fine, Admin-Login page too - but after login getting error 500
- Webhoster is domain factory (which limits access to log-files i.e. no access to apache logfiles via terminal)
- already tried developer mode and rebuilding static content, clearing cache

Comment: check this answer : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy/120109#answer-120109

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento 2 admin url not working and loaded frontend is all messy](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
I had checked the apache configuration and edited the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

My webhoster was able to give me access to a correct error.log file, sadly only for php5.6 (which the domain is running now). On php5.6 the error was solved by deactivating asp_tags for php.

Seems to be the same error solved in: [When i login the backend of magento2 have a Fatal error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92585/when-i-login-the-backend-of-magento2-have-a-fatal-error)

KAndy said that asp tags were removed in php7, but they're still in the php.ini configurator (sadly I don't have access to the direct file), disabling them worked on php7 too.

(so the domain is now running php7 again.)

But anyway - thanks for the help!